# Two equal power series with different centres

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Suppose $a_n$ for $n\geq 0$ is a complex number such that $$\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n(z-2i)^n=\sum_{n\geq 0}(n+1)z^n$$ holds for  each $z\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|z|<1$ and Im$(z)>0$ (imaginary part). Then show that $$\lim\sup\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\frac1{\sqrt{5}}.$$

I know that for the series $\sum_{n\geq 0}(n+1)z^n$, radius of convergence is $1$. This means the same is also true for the series given in left hand side. But how to connect this with $\lim\sup\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$?

Comment: You can sum up explicitly the right-hand side and see that it is a rational function with an isolated singularity at $z=1$. Then its power series expansion about $2i$ will have radius of convergence equal to the distance from $2i$ to $1$, which is $\sqrt{5}$. No use the Cauchy-Hadamard formula.

Answer (score 1):

A two-step approach. At first we transform the series $\sum_{n\geq 0}(n+1)z^n$ to determine $a_n$. Then we calculate the $\limsup$.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n\geq 0}(n+1)z^n
> &=\frac{d}{dz}\left(\sum_{n\geq 0} z^{n+1}\right)=\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{\left(\left(1-2i\right)-\left(z-2i\right)\right)^2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{(1-2i)^2}\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{-2}{n}\left(-\frac{z-2i}{1-2i}\right)^n\tag{1}\\
> &=\frac{1}{(1-2i)^2}\sum_{n\geq 0}\color{blue}{\frac{n+1}{(1-2i)^n}}(z-2i)^n\tag{2}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we make a *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*.
- In (2) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-2}{n}(-1)^n=\binom{n+1}{n}=n+1$.

> From (2) we derive
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\limsup_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}
> &=\limsup_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{n+1}{(1-2i)^n}\right|}\\
> &=\limsup_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{n+1}{|1-2i|^n}}\\
> &=\frac{1}{|1-2i|}\limsup_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{n+1}\\
> &=\frac{1}{|1-2i|}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.